# I seem to be painting under the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I've been trying to make a simple login program with a MYSQL database and when I added the JTextField and JPasswordField anything I paint under the paintComponent method appears to be covered. The problem where I can't see what I paint goes away when I don't add the panel which I need. Here is an example of my code.

```
public void createWindow(){
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setSize(1200, 720);
    etc.. all the necessary stuff
    //userfield is my JTextField
    panel.add(userfield);
    //This next line is the problem
    frame.add(panel);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("Hello", 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Going to need to see a runnable example before we can be 100% sure...but failing to call `super.paintComponent` won't be doing you any favors

Comment: What more code do you need to be sure? I actually just forgot to include that for my example sorry but it is in my actual code.

Comment: A runnable example that demonstrates the problem you are having.  Any ambiguity invites guess work which is waste of time on both our parts

Comment: The problem appears to be the JPanel painting overtop of what the paintComponent method does any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JPanel` is opaque by default, meaning that anything that it covers will not be painted.

Try making the `JPanel` transparent by using `JPanel#setOpaque` and passing it `false`

Comment: Note that based on your example code, you are going to have issues with ghost paint artifacts (components being painted twice), make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` from within the `paintComponent` method...